# How can I change the access rights of the device or add my user to the disk group in VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Arch noob here wishing to learn some fun new stuff. [Here is the guide I was looking into](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_from_VirtualBox)

In this link states that "your user must have write rights for the device." How can I achieve this in the Windows virtualbox environment? Much thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default installations of Virtual Box in Ubuntu 12.04 somehow neglects to add all users to the Virtual Box group, which of course you need to have for full operation.

However, it is easy to add the user back to the Virtual Box group. Here is how you do it:

1. Install "Users and Groups":

   sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
2. Launch terminal and type:

   users-admin
3. Click on the "Manage Groups" button
4. Scroll down to the group named: 'vboxusers' select it and click on "Properties" button
5. Check the checkbox near your username

That's it. It should work right away, but just in case you can logout and login again.

Hope that helps!